# Problem 1 while setting up Auh0 with composer. How do i fix this?

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, auth0

When I run:

`composer require hwi/oauth-bundle php-http/guzzle6-adapter php-http/httplug-bundle`

It gives this error:

> Problem 1
>       - Installation request for hwi/oauth-bundle ^0.6.3 -> satisfiable by hwi/oauth-bundle[0.6.3].
>       - hwi/oauth-bundle 0.6.3 requires php-http/httplug ^1.0 -> satisfiable by php-http/httplug[v1.0.0, v1.1.0].
>       - Can only install one of: php-http/httplug[v2.0.0, v1.0.0].
>       - Can only install one of: php-http/httplug[v2.0.0, v1.1.0].
>       - php-http/guzzle6-adapter v2.0.0 requires php-http/httplug ^2.0 -> satisfiable by php-http/httplug[v2.0.0].
>       - Installation request for php-http/guzzle6-adapter ^2.0 -> satisfiable by php-http/guzzle6-adapter[v2.0.0].

How do I fix this?

Comment: The error message is explaining the problem. `hwi/oauth-bundle` requires a version of `php-http/httplug` which is incompatible with `php-http/guzzle6-adapter` that you're also trying to install. You will need to find a version of `hwi/...` and `guzzle6-...` which both require the same version of `php-http/httplug`

Comment: thanks a lot robbie

Comment: @Htou, How you fixed this issue?

Comment: @ifran, I did not fix this issue, but someone from GitHub gave me a solution:  https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/issues/1448